# Vaadin 14,6 AppLayout with StatusBar?

Tags: java, layout, statusbar, vaadin14

I am happily using the standard [Vaadin AppLayout Component](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-app-layout/) as the layout starting point for my application. Now I received the requirement to add a statusbar. The statusbar must span the same width as the NavBar, so it cannot be part of the "content".

Is this at all possible with the default AppLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally AppLayout has been purposed to take over the whole space, so it is not really meant for this use case. However I was able to tweak it to behave fit footer bar with these settings.

```
public class MainLayout extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout {
    private AppLayout appLayout = new AppLayout();
    private FlexLayout childWrapper = new FlexLayout();

    public MainLayout() {
        ... setup appLayout ...
        childWrapper.setSizeFull();
        appLayout.setContent(childWrapper);

        HorizontalLayout statusBar = new HorizontalLayout();
        statusBar.setHeight("50px");
        statusBar.setWidth("100%");
        statusBar.add(new Span("Status Bar"));
        statusBar.getElement().getStyle().set("background",
                "var(--lumo-tint-30pct)");
        appLayout.getElement().getStyle().set("width", "100%");
        appLayout.getElement().getStyle().set("height", "500px");
        add(appLayout, statusBar);
        this.expand(appLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public void showRouterLayoutContent(HasElement content) {
        childWrapper.getElement().appendChild(content.getElement());
    }

}
```

If you are interested in the status bar to be on top instead, just switch `add(appLayout, statusBar);` to `add(statusBar, appLayout);`

Comment: Getting a usable result (at least for my application) seems to be a little more involved than the code snippet suggests. Firstly, the RouterLayout methods need to be forwarded to the AppLayout. There is some strange behaviour, though: the navigation side panel overlays the statusBar. Also, the statusBar on some screens just disappears when the screen is made vertically smaller. I will evaluate this further over the weekend.

Comment: If the navigation panel overlays the status bar anyways it might be an option to use another ParentLayout with a StatusBar for the AppLayout content and leave the AppLayout be the outermost component

Comment: > Firstly, the RouterLayout methods need to be forwarded to the AppLayout. 

Yes, that was so obvious that I skipped that part, but added now for sake of completeness, although it is a different question.