# Vaadin 14: Adding Footer application-wide to AppLayout

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14

I have a Vaadin Application where the MainLayout is of type AppLayout. We have an application-wide Navbar defined in this MainLayout and it works as expected. However I couldn't find a way to do the same for a footer. Is there a way to add a footer to AppLayout so it shows up at the bottom of every view?
I have tried [this solution](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18193739/footer-example-for-verticallayout) and adding the footer with `setContent()` but it's not showing.
Would be great if there was a way because adding this manually to each view would be a bit of a pain.

Thank you!

Comment: I think your question is essentially the same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68248661/vaadin-14-6-applayout-with-statusbar

Answer (score 2):

You could always create a RouterLayout that you will chain with your AppLayout and have fixed Footer and some container for routing targets.

Like:

```
@Route("")
@ParentLayout(MainLayout.class) // AppLayout
public class FooterLayout extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout {
    
    private Div container = new Div();
    
    private Div footer = new Div();

    public FooterLayout() {
        add(container, footer);
        footer.add(new Text("I'm a fixed footer!"));
    }

    public void showRouterLayoutContent(HasElement content) {
        container.removeAll();
        container.getElement().setChild(0, content.getElement());
    }
}
```