# Add footer using Vaadin framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, user-interface, vaadin, footer

I want to add a footer using vaadin framework, and I don't want to add it for all pages. With header everything was easy to set, but I don't find any up-to-date documentation on how to add also a footer on all pages.

```
public class MainLayout extends AppLayout {

    public MainLayout() {
        addHeader();
        addFooter();
    }

    private void addHeader() {
        Text text = new Text("This is a header");

        HorizontalLayout header = new HorizontalLayout(text);
        header.setWidth("100%");
        header.setDefaultVerticalComponentAlignment(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);

        addToNavbar(header);
    }

    private void addFooter() {
        Text text = new Text("This is a footer");

        HorizontalLayout footer = new HorizontalLayout(text);
        footer.setWidth("100%");
        footer.setDefaultVerticalComponentAlignment(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
        
        // Missing method to add footer like for header
    }
    
}
```

I also tried implementing it as an extension for MainLayout and still doesn't show the footer

```
@ParentLayout(MainLayout.class)
public class FooterLayout extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout {

    private final Div container = new Div();

    public FooterLayout() {
        Div footer = new Div();
        add(container, footer);
        footer.add(new Text("I'm a fixed footer!"));
        add(footer);
    }

    public void showRouterLayoutContent(HasElement content) {
        container.removeAll();
        container.getElement().setChild(0, content.getElement());
    }
}
```

Are there any solutions for my problem ? The main idea is that header and footer should be on every page that uses MainLayout

Answer (score 0):

Footer is not a feature in AppLayout. You have two options.

1. Do not use AppLayout, but create your own custom layout by composing layout components to achieve the desired result. I.e. implement RouterLayout interface and showRouterLayoutContent methods. This approach will allow you to do what ever you want.
2. You can also do the above so that you use AppLayout in the composition as a building block instead of extending it.

See also: [Vaadin 14: Adding Footer application-wide to AppLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72543362/vaadin-14-adding-footer-application-wide-to-applayout)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem with Vaadin documentation on adding a footer is that it doesn't work on my project because of `@Route("")` annotation(it's already used by MainView) and after removing it, the footer is not displayed at all. Maybe you know how to add it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You can try this:

```
public class CustomLayout extends VerticalLayout implements AfterNavigationObserver, RouterLayout {
AppLayout navigation;
Div container = new Div();
Div footer = new Div();

public CustomLayout(AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser, AccessAnnotationChecker accessChecker) {
    setSpacing(false);
    navigation = new Navigation(authenticatedUser, accessChecker);

    container.setSizeFull();

    add(navigation, container, footer);
    footer.add(new Text("I'm a fixed footer!"));
}

public void showRouterLayoutContent(HasElement content) {
    container.removeAll();
    container.getElement().setChild(0, content.getElement());
}

@Override
public void afterNavigation(AfterNavigationEvent event) {
    getElement().scrollIntoView();
}
```

}

And then inside your Views just add this:

```
@Route(value = "your-route-path", layout = CustomLayout.class)
```